# visualvm not part of OpenJDK7?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, java, visualvm

Neither in Ubuntu nor in Debian the tool visualvm is part of the OpenJDK 7 package. It's part of the Oracle JDK 7 and seems to be GPL licensed. While in Ubuntu it can be installed with a separate package, such a package doesn't exist in Debian.

Why isn't it part of the OpenJDK packages?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looking at Debian's [own information](http://packages.debian.org/sid/openjdk-7-jdk) on OpenJDK 7, we see that `visualvm` is indeed suggested but doesn't exist. If it is indeed a piece of software under the GPL (the 'net is rather frustrating on this point, but I might just be searching wrong, and I don't fancy downloading the whole lot just to research this point) then the reason for its absence is almost certainly prosaic: nobody's got around do doing the work to make it available as a Debian package.

Comment: VisualVM has the same license as OpenJDK. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VisualVM

Answer (score 34):

Our Ubuntu machine did not include VisualVM as part of the Java JDK. 
A quick search showed that the package was available as a separate install:

```
$ apt-cache search visualvm
...
visualvm - All-in-One Java Troubleshooting Tool
```

Quick Install:

```
$ apt-get install visualvm
```

After successful installation:

```
$ which jvisualvm 
/usr/bin/jvisualvm
```

I tried running it, but it kept complaining that it was using the JRE. I edited `/etc/visualvm/visualvm.conf`

```
# default location of JDK/JRE, can be overridden by using --jdkhome <dir> switch
jdkhome="/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64"
```

Comment: When I followed these steps, the program name that was installed was visualvm, not jvisualvm.  Otherwise, this worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to install VisualVM on Debian Wheezy by downloading the binary package for sid (http://packages.debian.org/sid/visualvm). All the dependencies were satisfied from wheezy without anything more from sid repositories, so basically my system is still stable.